# Angled Curve in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, technique

I've been going slightly crazy on trying to create even, curved lines

[image]

<sub>([click to see rest](https://imgur.com/a/4rCborJ))</sub>

The images I linked: 2nd top right angle curve is what I'm trying to achieve. The other two screenshots look like the curve is coming off a slightly sharp edge, and giving uneven spacing in the corners.

Are there any tips to get something similar to parallel, right angled lines (subway map or stripes on racing vehicles are the closest examples)?

Answer (score 4):

Use a stroke....

[image]

[image]

Stack multicolored strokes on the same path.
Align one to the outside (via the Stroke Panel)
Align another to the inside (via the Stroke Panel)
Then apply the Rounded Corners Effect to the shape.

Changing *where* the rounded corner item is in the Appearance panel will alter the rounding to a degree. Inevitably though, with this set up you can always expand things and adjust further if necessary.

You do have to use *closed shapes* to align the strokes this way. But you can always expand and then delete unwanted parts.

Comment: Thank you for this! I will continue to experiment for desired results.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is to create an Art Brush, and apply it to your path.

I'm not sure which version of Illustrator you have, but if you have the latest CC version it has [Live Corner widgets](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/reshape-with-live-corners.html) for rounding the corners.  However you could also just use the round corner effect.

Here's an example

[image]